# Positioning elements in css

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position, css-grid

[Visualization of what I need to program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkAfX.png)

What would be the ideal way of programming what is shown on the visualization?

I need to have h1 and a paragraph under that h1, h2 and a paragraph under that h2 to be on the left side and an image on the right side with use of "float:right" but I can't manage to make it happen.

Also, I need this whole "container" to appear in the middle of the webpage, just like it is on the image. I would be glad if someone could help.

I managed to make the whole thing to be in the center of the screen with use of this code, but I am sure this is not correct way of doing this.

I will share my HTML and CSS - what have I done so far and this is the most close I can come up with, but I am pretty sure it is not the correct way and it could be done in more correct way. For example I do not know what is the ideal position for the img tag to be placed in.

```
<div class="container">
<img src="/image.jpg">
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At dolore sed quisquam cumque laudantium animi qui culpa? Pariatur rerum tempora similique deleniti, eius perferendis, officia culpa vel aut dolorem porro.</p>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum eligendi sed, laboriosam a doloribus dolor. Et enim rerum mollitia tenetur ducimus magnam assumenda repudiandae fugiat aut laboriosam. Excepturi, quaerat sequi!</p>
</div>
```

```
.container{
    background-color: aqua;
    border: 1px black solid;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

img{
float: right;
}
```

When it comes to how many divs do I need (one for "container", one for left side with headings and paragraphs and one for img?) I am also not sure how to make it correctly. Currently I have just one div for container because it is at least somehow working.

I understand there is a lot of threads like this but I have been browsing all day through internet and couldn't make it so I am here. It would really help if someone would explain what would be the best way for programming this.

Answer (score 1):

```css
html{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  height: 100%;
  outline: 2px dashed red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
align-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
main {

  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  outline: 2px dashed blue;
}
section {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  
}
aside {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/astronaut-listening-music-with-headphone-peace-hand-cartoon-vector-icon-illustration-science-technology-icon-concept-isolated-premium-vector-flat-cartoon-style_138676-3375.jpg?auto=format&h=200");
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <h1>This is a tes</h1>
    <p>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</p>
    <h2>This is another test</h2>
    <p>gwerg werg werg werg werg werg werg werg werg werg werg </p>
  </section>
  <aside>
    
  <aside>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks Ronnie Royston, that would certainly do the thing, but I need to implement the float:right to the img just like I tried to do it myself (I edited the post so you can see it now).

Also I try to keep it as simple as possible. The thing is that I am not sure where to put the img or how to implement it so the float:right would do the thing. Right now I put it above the h1 so the float:right does at least something, but I think there is a different, more correct way to do it, that I am looking for.

Nevertheless, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified Ronnie's answer to fulfil your requirements. Remember that Flexbox is nothing that complicates our code, it's the other way round it makes it easier, sometimes it is not easy to understand, but once you get it you fall in love with Flexbox and Grid CSS. I recommend [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
html{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  height: 100%;
  outline: 2px dashed red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  outline: 2px dashed blue;
}
section {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 25px;
  
}
img {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <h1>This is a test</h1>
    <p>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</p>
    <h2>This is another test</h2>
    <p>gwerg werg werg werg werg werg werg werg werg werg werg werg werg werg werg werg werg werg</p>
  </section>
  <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/astronaut-listening-music-with-headphone-peace-hand-cartoon-vector-icon-illustration-science-technology-icon-concept-isolated-premium-vector-flat-cartoon-style_138676-3375.jpg?auto=format&h=200" />
</main>
```